# How to load different images in same view when we click on a each row of Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My Problem:

I am using two views, the first is a `TableView` and the other is `pagecurlViewController`. What I need is to have 20 rows in `tableview` and when I click on each row I need to load images in `pagecurlViewController`. I have 50 images in an array that I am facing trouble with. When I click on Row 1, it has all 50 images, and when I click on Row2, Row3, Row4....Row20 it also shows me that 50 images only. But what I need is to select 3 image in one particular row. Is there any code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you have only one section in table with 20 rows and all images are in your_ImageArray. Then you can try something  like bellow.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

int i = indexPath.row * 3;

 if(i < your_ImageArray.count - 3){
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

   NSLog(@"your image  = %@",[your_ImageArray objectAtIndex:i]);
   i++;

  }
}

}
```

But above code can give you exception of array out of bound cause according to your need your rows and array count do not match

Answer (score 0):

You should implement code in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and define `imageFunction:` method in `YourViewController.m`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourView animated:YES];
    if(!yourView)
    {
       yourView = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    [yourView imageFunction:[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourView animated:YES];

}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Hello prasad I place my viewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but what I need is when I click on particular row the Particular image should load and as usaual if I select row2 it should load more different images not that previous images....please can you help me solve this problem.. please

Comment: Prasad my problem is I have my first view is TableView and in that I have 20 rows in one section and in second view i have pageviewcontroller when ever I select a rows I am getting same images.. what I need is when ever I select I need different different Images in same PageViewContoller itself please help me please....

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just want to select image by table view.

This is selection table view.

[image: selection]

And this is detail view.

[image: detail]

At first, I made property `arrayImg`.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.arrayImg = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"], nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, I wrote the cell selection code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImage" sender:s];
}
```

At last, I made `prepareForSegue` method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DetailViewController *d = segue.destinationViewController;
    d.strImgName = sender;
}
```

In the detail view, I just wrote below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:strImgName];
}
```

The whole project is here:https://github.com/weed/p120801_ImageSelectorWithTableView

You can download sample project and just run it.

I wish my trial is help for you.